# Cannot replicate a crash found by AppleConnect. Xcode 13.2, iOS 15.2

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I am getting a rejection from the App Store, based on a crash. I cannot replicate the crash on any of my iOS and iPad devices.

I'm attaching the Apple log.

I'm not an expert in reading crash logs, but I did notice a reference to this in each report: "bug_type":"309". Several large companies have apparently been plagued with this one.

I also see this line:

```
"exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000104ee8264","rawCodes":[1,4377707108],"type":"EXC_BREAKPOINT","signal":"SIGTRAP"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":5,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Trace\/BPT trap: 5","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":4699},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
```

Crash log:

```
{"app_name":"My GPS Locator","timestamp":"2021-12-23 16:50:52.00 -0800","app_version":"1.2.2","slice_uuid":"2712d3dc-74a7-35ae-a4e2-40b426ec539a","adam_id":"1601245191","build_version":"211225.1","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.bohtech.mygpslocator","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 15.2 (19C56)","incident_id":"A7C85DD0-422F-479D-B19E-B32AFAEE45A6","name":"My GPS Locator"}
{
  "uptime" : 480000,
  "procLaunch" : "2021-12-23 16:50:50.4428 -0800",
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad11,3",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 11623364001232,
  "coalitionID" : 1931,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 15.2",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "19C56"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2021-12-23 16:50:52.5983 -0800",
  "incident" : "A7C85DD0-422F-479D-B19E-B32AFAEE45A6",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 4699,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 11623415571500,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "My GPS Locator",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/53F96106-9950-4304-8EEE-A7C730BD41C7\/My GPS Locator.app\/My GPS Locator",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.2.2","CFBundleVersion":"211225.1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.bohtech.mygpslocator","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"13C90b"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"1601245191","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"1637A6EC-1F73-4AE1-B51C-DBBB61FD5019","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"846096774"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.bohtech.mygpslocator",
  "crashReporterKey" : "61aa2a741550be1682565c0c402e07307dfbc328",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000104ee8264","rawCodes":[1,4377707108],"type":"EXC_BREAKPOINT","signal":"SIGTRAP"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":5,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Trace\/BPT trap: 5","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":4699},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":1944125,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":10756747456},{"value":4},{"value":6788522916,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"nanov2_free_definite_size"},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":4379821664,"symbolLocation":224,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":0},{"value":2045},{"value":1},{"value":157},{"value":3397797938},{"value":3399897088},{"value":413696},{"value":6900960208,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue"},{"value":6788470352,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"default_zone_free_definite_size"},{"value":4594755996},{"value":4437662208},{"value":4437662208},{"value":4377747492},{"value":4437662208},{"value":4377747492},{"value":7990942464,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"UIApp"},{"value":0},{"value":7733771433,"objc-selector":"objectAtIndex:"},{"value":10741842496},{"value":1}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4377707064},"cpsr":{"value":2147483648},"fp":{"value":6089216192},"sp":{"value":6089216176},"esr":{"value":4060086273,"description":"(Breakpoint) brk 1"},"pc":{"value":4377707108,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":7982208624}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":49764,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":49720,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":49796,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":5019004,"symbol":"-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]","symbolLocation":100,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":6248560,"symbol":"-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]","symbolLocation":128,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":3607156,"symbol":"-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]","symbolLocation":352,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":4248392,"symbol":"-[UIButton _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":6948344,"symbol":"-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]","symbolLocation":536,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1517744,"symbol":"-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]","symbolLocation":980,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1720940,"symbol":"-[UIWindow sendEvent:]","symbolLocation":4456,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":3492120,"symbol":"-[UIApplication sendEvent:]","symbolLocation":828,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1537124,"symbol":"__dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue","symbolLocation":7904,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1491536,"symbol":"__processEventQueue","symbolLocation":6760,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1513212,"symbol":"__eventFetcherSourceCallback","symbolLocation":172,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":766160,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__","symbolLocation":28,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":834960,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSource0","symbolLocation":208,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":24728,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSources0","symbolLocation":268,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":47268,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":820,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":128104,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":600,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":5004,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5349512,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":1100,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2722136,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":2092,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":200608,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:)","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":18128,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":105124,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":520,"imageIndex":5}]},{"id":1944126,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944127,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944128,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944129,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944130,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":5380,"symbol":"mach_msg_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":7068,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":30520,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":372,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":47660,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1212,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":128104,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":600,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":101524,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":236,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":368072,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":92,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":4796976,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":524,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":427020,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":808,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":6564,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":3744,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944131,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944132,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944133,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944135,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944136,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944137,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944138,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944139,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944140,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944141,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1944142,"frames":[{"imageOffset":3724,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4377657344,
    "size" : 98304,
    "uuid" : "2712d3dc-74a7-35ae-a4e2-40b426ec539a",
    "path" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/53F96106-9950-4304-8EEE-A7C730BD41C7\/My GPS Locator.app\/My GPS Locator",
    "name" : "My GPS Locator"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6527549440,
    "size" : 25735168,
    "uuid" : "cd7f7ba2-a2c6-3727-aff6-9baab60cc6ab",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
    "name" : "UIKitCore"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6489116672,
    "size" : 4538368,
    "uuid" : "16faa70c-278c-3561-859e-cec407c2dc7c",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6954332160,
    "size" : 36864,
    "uuid" : "064a1bb6-0e41-3ad2-a402-fb563fc141f5",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/GraphicsServices.framework\/GraphicsServices",
    "name" : "GraphicsServices"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6884171776,
    "size" : 446464,
    "uuid" : "101fe096-8d8b-33d5-913b-c31c5d26c5f2",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/swift\/libswiftUIKit.dylib",
    "name" : "libswiftUIKit.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4379377664,
    "size" : 360448,
    "uuid" : "f94ccc7a-6d1a-33c7-997f-f611a6caa7e0",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 8360894464,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "c5c27e9d-9557-39c9-b9c6-5f6e7323ee1c",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7405334528,
    "size" : 212992,
    "uuid" : "eb3e47f3-3953-3583-9fee-fb6cff8a8d7a",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 6514425856,
    "size" : 3174400,
    "uuid" : "9618b2f2-a4c2-3e07-b7ee-d8d9e1bdeaec",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 6485688320,
  "size" : 2452996096,
  "uuid" : "30b98d3f-198e-3ace-a71e-1aa35b3a44f2"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=632.5M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=632.5M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=851.8M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=851.8M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nAccelerate framework               128K        1 \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nColorSync                           80K        5 \nCoreAnimation                     15.4M       14 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nImage IO                          1056K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           825.3M      215 \nMALLOC guard page                  512K       32 \nSTACK GUARD                        272K       17 \nStack                             9712K       17 \nVM_ALLOCATE                        464K        8 \n__AUTH                            3073K      318 \n__AUTH_CONST                      17.7M      445 \n__DATA                            9779K      434 \n__DATA_CONST                      17.6M      452 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      1824K      371 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       185.5M        5 \n__OBJC_CONST                      4082K      294 \n__OBJC_RO                         90.3M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3408K        1 \n__TEXT                           447.0M      463 \n__UNICODE                          588K        1 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nmapped file                       44.8M       16 \nshared memory                       48K        3 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.6G     3119 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "601d9415f79519000ccd4b69",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_TEXT_TO_SPEECH" : "6194416f2171a2330e561f05"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000341
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}
```

Comment: Do they supply you with a symbolicatable crash log? Have you tested a TestFlight build? On a device with no network? On a pure ipv6 network. On a device that has never had a build of your app on it?

Comment: That trap indicates a dynamic library could not be loaded at runtime. Check you pods or swift packages. Are you building with an m1 Mac or Intel?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. I did not get a symbolicatable crash log; just 3 reports showing three different crashes. I've tested on ~6 devices, none of which had a build previously. I only use 1 pod (MarqueeLabel), so I'll integrate that into the project. I'm building on an M1 Mac.

Comment: I'll try without a pod file, and I'll rework the three buttons that Apple said are causing the crashes. I'm open to other suggestions of course

Comment: There are reports of dynamic library link problems with pods causing this crash on m1 Mac builds. Are your tests with test flight builds?

Comment: Thanks Paul,  No, I don't have reliable testers to use TestFlight. I've removed the Pod. I'll see what happens.. Fingers crossed

Comment: Why can't you test it yourself with TestFlight?

Comment: I've now tested the app in TestFlight. It works on both iOS and macOS.